# Loading emoji Unicode from excel file to a list

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, xlrd

I have an excel sheet with emoji-unicode like this:

```
\U0001F602
\U0001F603
```

When i load them from excel to a list, they are
converted to "\\U0001F602" instead of "\U0001F602".

Code is:

```
def emoji_table():

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('emoji.xlsx')   
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('emoji_sheet')   
    num_rows = worksheet.nrows
    emoji_list = []

    i=0
    for emoji in  range(0,num_rows):
        emoji_cell_value = str(worksheet.col(0)[i].value).encode("utf-8")
        emoji_cell_value = emoji_cell_value.decode()        
        emoji_list.append(str(emoji_cell_value))
        i+=1

    print (">>>>emoji_list>>>>")
    print (emoji_list)
```

The result:

```
>>>>emoji_list>>>>
['\\U0001F602', '\\U0001F603']
```

Notice that if I add items to a list like this:

```
list1.append('\U0001F602')
```

and then encode/decode them, it works.

So the issue with double "\\" exists only when i grab those Unicode characters from the excel file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, i figured it out.

I changed the decode to **unicode-escape** and now it works fine.

```
emoji_cell_value = emoji_cell_value.decode("unicode-escape")
```